# Getting 3 full years in json format

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

What would be the best way to create a json object with a 3 full years.

For example:

```
{
    2017:{
        jan:[
            {day:'monday', timestamp:12512421},
            {day:'tuseday', timestamp:151512}
        ]...
    },
    2018:{
        jan:[
                {day:'monday', timestamp:12512421},
                {day:'tuseday', timestamp:151512}
        ]...
    }
    2019:{
        jan:[
            {day:'monday', timestamp:12512421},
            {day:'tuseday', timestamp:151512}
        ]...
    }
}
```

I need to be able to display a week’s in the future. That is for example: what dates are in week 8 on the year 2019. I need some idea of where to start to start formulating the json object… or if it already exists in some kind of library.

But I’m not sure what would be the start to start trying out.

Comment: Please share the code which you have tried.

Comment: What do you want the output to be? If that's the output, what's the input for that output?

Comment: Why do you want to create such json? May be you can achieve end usecase without doing this.

Comment: I can see that I was not clear enough, sorry about that. 

I need the data in json format, and there would not be any input. I need to be able to display a week’s in the future. That is for example: what dates are in week 8 on the year 2019.

I need some idea of where to start to start formulating the json object… or if it already exists in some kind of library. But I’m not sure what would be the start to start trying out.

Comment: @B-boy we need a more concrete example. It could be that what you are asking is for a calendar, a way to calculate week days at any arbitrary date. It could also be that you are asking just for how to structure the data... More context is needed to understand what are you asking. What is this JSON for?

Comment: Do you need the epoch timestamp for each day? Or just the date like "Monday January 3 2076?"

Comment: I would save the dates in an array and do the separation in code

Comment: @istepaniuk I am trying to create a react booking system with a weekly calendar display.

Comment: I don't have enough rep to comment, but maybe moment.js could be what you need? With moment, you can find out what dates are in week 8 on the year 2019, for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if this is a good way of achieving this... but anyways this is how i have it now.

```
setYearObject(yearStart, yearEnd) {
    let obj = {};
    let start = new Date(yearStart,0);
    let currentYear = yearStart;
    let currentDay = start;
    let week = [];

    while(currentYear <= yearEnd){    
        obj[currentYear] = [];
        currentYear++;
    }
    currentYear = yearStart;
    console.log(currentDay.getDate());
    while(currentYear !== parseInt(yearEnd) +1){
        week[currentDay.getDay()] = {day: currentDay.getDate(), month:currentDay.getMonth(), dayOfWeek: this.getWeekday(currentDay.getDay())}

        if(currentDay.getDay() >= 6){
            obj[currentYear].push(week);
            week = [];
        }
        currentDay.setDate(currentDay.getDate() + 1);
        currentYear = currentDay.getFullYear();
    }

    for (var property in obj) {
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
            let tmpYear = parseInt(property);
            if(obj[property].length <=52 && obj[property].length >= 1){
                // obj[(tmpYear)].push(obj[(tmpYear + 1)][0])
                console.log(obj[tmpYear + 1])
                if( obj[tmpYear + 1] !== undefined){
                    if((obj[tmpYear +1]).length >= 1){
                        obj[tmpYear].push(obj[tmpYear + 1 ][0]);
                    }  
                }
            }
        }
      }
    console.log(obj);
    return obj;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function setYearObject(yearStart, yearEnd) {
    const obj = {};
    const start = new Date(yearStart, 0);
    const end = new Date(yearEnd, 0);
    const months = {
     Jan: [], Feb: [], Mar: [], Apr: [], May: [], Jun: [],
        Jul: [], Aug: [], Sep: [], Oct: [], Nov: [], Dec: []
    };
 
    while (yearStart < yearEnd) { obj[yearStart++] = months  }
    while (start < end) {
        const timeStamp = start.getTime()
        const parts = start.toDateString().split(" ");
        const year = start.getFullYear().toString()
 
        obj[year][parts[1]].push({ day: parts[0], timeStamp: timeStamp });
        start.setDate(start.getDate() + 1);
    }
    return obj;
}

console.log(setYearObject(2017, 2020))
```

Comment: This did not work for me.. but it helped me achive what i needed to finish my code :) thanks